# In Flutter, how to use Null Safety in Future?

Tags: flutter, future, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to migrate to Null Safety in Flutter. The following code snippet to convert ImageProvider to ByteData works fine without Null Safety.

```
static Future<ByteData> imgProvider2ByteData(ImageProvider img) async {
Completer<ByteData> completer = new Completer<ByteData>();
img
    .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
    .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      completer.complete(info.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png));
}));
return completer.future;
```

}

```
///pass ImageProvider to above function 

ImageProvider provider=....

imgProvider2ByteData(provider).then((val) {
        var data = val.buffer.asUint8List();
 });
```

After enabling Null Safety, the function toByteData return Future<ByteData?> so I made the following changes (adding ? on type and ! on Future return value):

```
static Future<ByteData?> imgProvider2ByteData(ImageProvider img) async {
Completer<ByteData?> completer = new Completer<ByteData>();
img
    .resolve(new ImageConfiguration())
    .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
      completer.complete(info.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png));
}));
return completer.future;
```

}

```
    /*pass ImageProvider to above function */

ImageProvider provider=....

imgProvider2ByteData(provider).then((val) {
        var data = val!.buffer.asUint8List();
 });
```

When I run it, I got the following error:

> Exception caught by image resource service
> type 'Future<ByteData?>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr?' of 'value'

I must have done something wrong but can't figure how to use Null Safety on Future return value. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Since `toByteData()` returns a `Future<ByteData?>`, you should also return the same from your method. Try this:

```dart
Future<ByteData?> imgProvider2ByteData(ImageProvider img) async {
  var completer = Completer<ByteData?>();
  img.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
    completer.complete(info.image.toByteData());
  }));
  return completer.future;
}
```